# Warning: "Intersecting linear/additive predictors" when fitting non-proportional odds ordinal regression model with VGLM()

Tags: r, ordinal, error-messaging, vgam

I am fitting a partial proportional odds cumulative logit ordinal regression model. Response is an ordinal diagnosis, predictors are two urinary biomarkers. I fit the model using the following command:

```
fit=vglm(diagnosis ~ creatinine + LYVE1, data=urine.dat, 
    family=cumulative(parallel=F))
summary(fit)
```

Afterwards, I often get about 20 of the following warnings:

```
In slot(family, "validparams")(eta, y, extra = extra) :
    It seems that the nonparallelism assumption has resulted in    
    intersecting linear/additive predictors.  
    Try propodds() or fitting a partial nonproportional odds model or  
    choosing some other link function, etc.
```

Does anyone understand what is meant by "intersecting linear/additive predictors?" From what I have seen, this error is returned very often with non-proportional odds VGLM models. Just trying to understand what is the issue with the model.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I think the warning comes from assuming a cumulative probability model, but that the estimated model (at least for some iterations) does not appropriately estimate the cumulative probabilities.  I'm not sure why there would be a `parallel=FALSE` option, when that is likely to give rise to this error.  You could use `multinomial()` instead or use `clm()` from the `ordinal` package where you can specify some or all variables as nominal (the generalized ordered logic model).

Comment: What do you mean by not appropriately estimate the cumulative probabilities? I need parallel=FALSE as the covariates do not satisfy the proportional odds assumption.

Comment: I posted an answer that explains.

Answer (score 0):

If you look through the `VGAM` source code, you'll find the following piece that throws the warning:

```r
    probs <-
      if ( .reverse ) {
        ccump <- cbind(1, eta2theta(eta, .link , earg = .earg ))
        cbind(-tapplymat1(ccump, "diff"), ccump[, ncol(ccump)])
      } else {
        cump <- cbind(eta2theta(eta, .link , earg = .earg ), 1)
        cbind(cump[, 1], tapplymat1(cump, "diff"))
      }
    okay1 <- all(is.finite(probs)) && all(0 < probs & probs < 1)
    if (!okay1)
      warning("It seems that the nonparallelism assumption has ",
              "resulted in intersecting linear/additive ",
              "predictors.  Try propodds() or fitting a partial ",
              "nonproportional odds model or choosing ",
              "some other link function, etc.")
```

We can boil the guts of this down to a couple of different pieces:

```r
library(VGAM)
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> Loading required package: splines
fit=vglm(cyl ~ wt, data=mtcars, 
         family=cumulative(parallel=F))

eta <- predict(fit, type="link")
cump <- cbind(VGAM:::eta2theta(eta, logitlink ), 1)
probs <- cbind(cump[, 1], tapplymat1(cump, "diff"))
```

Since `cyl` has three values, `eta` is an Nx2 matrix of predicted values on the link scale.  `cump` is the matrix of cumulative probabilities calculated in the usual way for ordered logit.  `probs` is the matrix of category probabilities calculated in the usual way for ordered logit - by subtracting the previous cumulative probability from the current one.  Once these are calculated, a flag is generated to identify whether all probabilities are finite and in the theoretical bounds:

```r
okay1 <- all(is.finite(probs)) && all(0 < probs & probs < 1)
#> [1] FALSE
```

In this case `okay1` is `FALSE`.  We can see why below:

```r
all(is.finite(probs))
#> [1] TRUE
all(0 < probs & probs < 1)
#> [1] FALSE
```

It's because some of the predicted probabilities are negative.  We can see which ones below:

```r
ind <- which(probs < 0 | probs > 1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]
ind
#> row 
#>  16

probs[ind, ]
#>                    logitlink(P[Y<=2])                    
#>       1.253506e-04      -2.167395e-12       9.998746e-01
```

Notice here that the predicted probabilities for the second group are negative (though not much different from zero).  The takeaway here is that even though you have specified `parallel=FALSE`, the resulting model is incompatible with the underlying cumulative probability assumption.  The warning is encouraging you to use a different model that doesn't calculate probabilities this way, like multinomial logit.  For example:

```r
fit2=vglm(cyl ~ wt, data=mtcars, 
         family=multinomial())
```

which doesn't throw a warning because the probabilities are calculated in a way that won't allow them to be outside [0,1], so long as the exponentiated predicted values on the link scale are finite.

<sup>Created on 2022-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you have a link where I might find the source code? I am able to find some, but not the section you are referring to.

Comment: @Timofei you can download the source code for the package from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/VGAM_1.1-6.tar.gz).  Unzip the file.  If you're working in RStudio, you can open a project in the rot folder of the package.  Then, you can use Edit >> Find in Folders and search for "propodds()".  That will identify two files - familyname.Rd and family.categorical.R. If you look in the family.categorical.R file, you'll find the section I referenced in the answer around line 1535.